# I am trying to transfer data from a few rows in a single column using python 3.8.3, openpyxl, on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, openpyxl, data-transfer, python-3.8

I have successfully opened my workbook and I am attempting to test this code. I want to view the data in the first few cells. I cant tell if it is working and I think I am using the print function incorrectly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64FxZ.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and typing out your code instead of linking to it?

Answer (score 0):

U'd better post ur code here not image link.

Using code below may work well.

eg:

```
def get_cell_values(ws):   # ws : work_sheet
    return [cell.value for (row,cell),cell in ws._cells.items()]
```